# Stretching a parametric plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the simple parametric function given by

```
ParametricPlot[{0.5 x (1 - x^2), 0.5 x (1 + x^2)}, {x, 0, 0.75}, 
  AxesLabel -> {a, b}]
```

*Mathematica* plots it but the graph is squashed. Is there a way to stretch the axes (in particular the a-axis) so it looks more presentable. Thanks.

Comment: Try `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio` or `AspectRatio -> 1`

Comment: Works well enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[{0.5 x (1 - x^2), 0.5 x (1 + x^2)}, {x, 0, 0.75},
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
  AxesLabel -> {a, b}]
```

[image: plot]